# Merge duplicate records then pullout data from another sheet using vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to merge to duplicate records then concatenate and sum columns then within the loop i want to update a column to pullout data from another sheet using vlookup. The code error is out of range.

```
Sub CombineDuplicateRecords()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Variant: columnToConcatenate = 2
        Dim columnToSum As Integer: columnToSum = 13
        Dim columntoUpdate As Variant: columntoUpdate = 14

        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & ", " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columntoUpdate) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(lngRow - 1, 1), Sheets(Sheet2).Range("A13:Z"), columnToUpdate, False)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) + .Cells(lngRow, columnToSum)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

> Out of range

Comment: What line shows the error?  What are the values of the variables within that line at the time? Also, if, in the immediate window, you type `?.Name` or `?ActiveSheet.Name`, is the sheet name returned what you expect?

Comment: The second line after the if- the columntoupdate.

Comment: Once you figure out the answers to my other questions, your problem should become evident.

Comment: Edited the line with the vlookup and change the sheetname. Now the error is data type mismatch. The variable that i declared is a variant and the source range that will be matched i already converted it to a number same thing with the search argument.